Should I contact potential PhD supervisor of a pre-defined project?
I want to apply to some PhD projects in the UK (all either already funded or competition-funded). Most of the posts that I can find regarding contacting supervisors mention contacting them for self-defined (as in the PhD student) projects.
Is the etiquette the same when the project topic and basic outlines are already defined and the supervisor is expecting applicants to said project?

Yes, and that helps them quite a bit. If you contact them and they are interested in you, they will probably book a informal chat so they can see if you are a good fit to the project. Others might just talk to you via email. Either way, showing interest is key and can help you quite a lot. Some programs also require proof that the supervisor is willing to supervise you, so taking to them is the only way to get into those.
